# The name '###' does not exist in the current content (wave of these on every page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

When any .cs page is opened a slew of "does not exist..." errors show up with an occasional "are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Although these errors appear, the project can build and run just fine. I can even step through the code. In fact when it is built the errors go away.

Once the run has ended, adding a new page will generate all the same messages for that page and any previous one opened that session.

I have done several searches but these error seems fairly generic and I have not found an answer that works for me just yet.

**EDIT:** A bit of elaboration on when it first showed up might help - My coworker made some changes by adding a brand new aspx page to our project while I fixed a code issue on a separate page. We used Source Safe go get his changes into my project. Ever since we used Source Safe it seems some configuration was changed with Visual Studio. Both our projects worked fine on separate machine, but now neither runs without these errors.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing the project layout, the specific '###' messages or how the assemblies it claims are missing are linked to your project.

Comment: It's just a shot in the dark without more details, but I've seen similar issues when "Target framework" in project properties is set to a "Client Profile" version of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Seems quite weird.... and It's hard to answer without more info. Have you tried to Clean and Rebuild the whole solution?

Comment: It has been rebuilt more than LEGO's But thanks for the idea regardless!

Comment: Yeah I realize it is very difficult to help with the limited info and trust me I wish I could release some. I imagine it has to be some sort of configuration issue since we didn't really change any code between the errors.

Comment: You can't possibly expect any useful answers if you can't provide any information at all. That's very unfortunate for you.

Comment: Considering I'm not sure what the issue is, I can't rule out the possibility that there is a simple setting I may have missed that conflicts with Source Safe or some other small thing. I realize people cannot psychically read my code and evaluate it, but maybe I just don't know something small.

Comment: Have any folders in the project changed?  Could a reference to another project or DLL be broken?  Look at the references for each project to see if there's a culprit there.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. I have VS2008 professional. After installing SP1, my copy of VS2008 now generates huge amounts of "does not exist" errors. The code is absolutely perfect, the errors are false reports. If I rebuild, all of the errors disappear. However, simply typing 1 character into any open .cs file will bring back all the errors. They do not go away after waiting.

Other people reporting this bug, say that double clicking an error makes it go away. Not the case for me however.

This is deffo a bug in VS2008SP1. It has to do with the background compilation not working or something. Anybody else have the same issue?

This might fix the issue:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kevinpilchbisson/archive/2008/10/30/hotfix-for-vs2008-sp1-available.aspx

Haven't tried it yet.

Anybody have this issue, clearly a BIG problem with VS2008SP1?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I fixed it. I simply deleted the SUO file for my web project. The strange behaviour "seems" to have gone now for this project.

Before deleting the file I noticed that there were lots of breakpoints set up and each of these breakpoints had lots of "sub breakpoints". Don't know what that was all about, but it looked odd.

But deleting the suo file tidied all of this up.  Breakpoints look OK now. Breaks and steps OK. Live semantic markup is OK. At least for the moment!

If you are getting issues, try deleting the suo file. Won't always work but is worth a try...